# How to draw a rectangle with edge roughness

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I use Imagedraw module to draw rectangle, which is very simple:

```
blank=Image.new("RGB",[pixelx,pixely],"black:")
draw=ImageDraw.Draw(blank)
draw.rectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2,fill='white')
```

This gives me a straight line rectangle in white.

But can I change the roughness of edge of this rectangle?

I am trying to make the rectangle look more similar to practical image.

If I cannot achieve this by Imagedraw, what module can help me do that.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know precisely what effect you are after.

I can tell you that Pillow has filters - https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.2.x/reference/ImageFilter.html

```
from PIL import ImageFilter
im = im.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
```

Changing the angle of your rectangle - by selecting co-ordinates that are not a flat rectangle - would create pixelated edges.

Otherwise, I might suggest randomly changing individual pixels along the edges using https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.2.x/reference/PixelAccess.html

```
from PIL import Image
px = im.load()
px[0, 0] = (0, 0, 0)
```

Although that could be slow. It depends on the size of your image and the need for speed.